# How to launch Scala from prompt

Tags: scala

I downloaded Scala from http://www.scalalang.org/downloads and I would like to start to do simple program starting from prompt and using the interpreter.

Could you explain step by step how I can launch a simple Hello World

Thanks

Comment: There are instructions for running hello world at http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html. Delicious!

Comment: Bon appetit :))

Comment: Glad you're trying Scala! If you describe more about what isn't working about the instructions, we might be able to help you more specifically.

Comment: @SethTisue in 2.12, no longer necessary to do weird call to main in script it! You'll get `warning: Script has a main object but statement is disallowed`. Too bad someone downvoted this important and non-trivial question. If SO comes out on the wrong side of history, it will be for their implementation of the downvote.

Comment: Is this question edible er editable ?

Comment: @TimHarper The last step in the getting started script at https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html#your-first-lines-of-code, where we are invited to run some Scala as a script, does not work in the Scala I just down loaded: 2.12.2. A little surprising that has not been fixed.

Comment: @som-snytt Thx! To others, the fix then is to delete the entire last line: ````HelloWorld.main(args)````

Comment: @som-snytt I also had the same warning, `Script has a main object but statement is disallowed` and the script didn't run but no error reported. What are the likely causes to it? Thanks

Comment: @YanqiHuang that is a warning that the main object is not used as entry point. The file is run as script, wrapped in main method. Try -Xprint:typer or -Vprint:typer in 2.13 to see how it was wrapped. Then try gitter for more questions.

Answer (score 3):

To launch a prompt

add the scala's bin directory to $PATH variable and type `scala` command.

## Simple script

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala
println("Hello World")
```

Save it as `hello.scala`

```
chmod +x hello.scala

./hello.scala
#or 
scala hello.scala
```